Is it possible to limit the scikit learn model to only predict certain tags?
I have two models trained on a number of tags and use it for predicting the genre of a game. I noticed that due to have the models were trained, sometimes the same input data can have the two models output wildly different genres.
I would like to limit the predictions to what the other model suggested but do not know how to do this. example below
Model1_labels = ["JRPG", "Horror", "FPS", "Platformer"]
Model2_Labels = ["Mario", "War_shooter", "fantasy_rpg"]

training_data = Label1      Label2            Tags
               JRPG        fantasy_rpg       open_world, action, level-up, fantasy
               JRPG        fantasy_rpg       level-up, turn-based, fantasy
               FPS         War_shooter       open-world, 1st person, tanks, planes, shooter
               FPS         War_shooter       1st person, war, shooter, level-up
               JRPG        Mario             level-up, turn-based, shooter
               ...

from the example, War_shooter can only ever be an FPS as the description of a war shooter is a fps game set during the war.
but how to limit?
code for how I train and predict below:
SDG_PARAMS_DICT: Final[Dict[str, Any]] = dict(alpha=1e-5, penalty="l2", max_iter=1000, loss="log_loss")
VECTORIZER_PARAMS_DICT: Final[Dict[str, Any]] = dict(ngram_range=(1, 4), min_df=5, max_df=0.8)
def build_model(x_data, y_data) -> Pipeline:
    game_predict_pipeline = Pipeline(
        [
            ("vect", CountVectorizer(VECTORIZER_PARAMS_DICT)),
            ("tfidf", TfidfTransformer()),
            ("clf", SelfTrainingClassifier(SGDClassifier(**SDG_PARAMS_DICT), verbose=True)),
        ]
    )
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_data,
                                                        y_data,
                                                        train_size=0.3)
     game_predict_pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)

     return game_predict_pipeline 

 game_data = pd.read_excel("c:/my_game_data.xlsx", keep_default_na=False)

 model1 = build_model(game_data["Tag"], game_data["Label1"])
 model2 = build_model(game_data["Tag"], game_data["Label2"])

 test_tags = "level-up, open-world, shooter"

 model1.predict(test_tag)
 model2.predict(test_tag)

results
model1 - correct
   FPS
model2 - incorrect
   Mario

I thought about performing predict_proba and removing labels form the list but his doesn't change the probability of the prediction resulting in many scores not reaching a theoretical cutoff
comparison_dict: Dict = {"FPS":["War_shooter"]}


prediction2: np.ndarray = model2.predict_proba(test_tag)
classes: np.ndarray = model2.classes_
prediction_dict: Dict = {}
for idx, model_cls in enumerate(classes):
    if model_cls in comparison_dict.get(model1_precition):
        if prediction2[0][idx] < 0.6: # cutoff
              prediction_dict[model_cls] = prediction2[0][idx]

the results
output predict_proba
    Mario      : 0.43
    War_shooter: 0.42
    fantasy_rpg: 0.15

output
    None

output without cutoff
    "War_shooter": 0.42

